# Alignment in Flex table

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

How can I get the flex table (flex3) to align at the top in [this Ui](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxGQS_xrPZMcxQ6uzTErFzdzd_hO2JNwetOnKNkrbIOt0PYB1Q/exec)?

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var flex1 = app.createFlexTable().setBorderWidth(1);
  var flex2 = app.createFlexTable().setBorderWidth(1).setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('flex2'))
      .setWidget(1, 0, app.createTextArea().setHeight(400).setText('Text area in flex2'));
  var flex3 = app.createFlexTable().setBorderWidth(1).setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('flex3'));

  flex1.setWidget(0, 0, flex2).setWidget(0, 1, flex3);  
  app.add(flex1);
  return app;
}
```

Was expecting...

`var flex1 = app.createFlexTable().setBorderWidth(1).setStyleAttribute('vertical-align', 'top');`

or

```
var flex1 = app.createFlexTable().setBorderWidth(1).setColumnStyleAttribute(1, 'vertical-align', 'top');
```

to work.

Also, using a flow panel instead of a flex for the root didn't work as expected either.  That stacked the 2 flex vertically and not left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line towards the bottom did the trick for me -

```
flex1.setStyleAttribute(0, 1, 'vertical-align', 'top');
```

Not sure why the global set style or set column style didn't work. However, setting it on a specific row/column seem to work. Let me know.

This might have to end up on the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), please check there and log an issue.

Comment: Thx, think I was just doing it wrong.  Trying to set styling on a column that didn't exist yet.  Maybe you're just not suppose to be able to do until after you use setWidget / setText and specify a row & col to create.